# Razor not rendering special characters properly

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm generating cshtml files dynamically for our CMS and using UTF-8 as encoding. I also tried to open those files using Notepad++ and it says that the encoding is UTF-8.

And I just use the controller's `View()` method to serve the page:

```
return View(path);
```

But it still improperly renders the special characters to a wrong one. Like 'α' becoming 'Î±', or single quote becoming 'â€™'. The generated files when inspecting contains the correct characters, but when it getting served, it shows incorrect characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and solution. The cshtml files should be written not by simple UTF8 format, but UTF8-BOM file format. Non-BOM UTF8 cshtml files' special characters were converted into something when getting served through `return View(path);`.